# DB Schema Compare Report

Tags: compare, database-schema

I need a way to generate a report from the result of using Visual Studios Schema Compare tool. Is there a way to generate a report from the result in a portable format (e.g. HTML for example) using the .scmp file that can be produced from saving the result?

Opening the file in a text editor its obviously XML but not presented in a very easily comprehensible format for an end user to understand. I need to produce a visual that would minimally be a representation of the visual output given within Visual Studio.

Is this possible?